# How to find a view field variable name in Drupal 7

Tags: view, drupal-7, nodequeue

Hello I want to ask is it possible to take the value of a field (from a drupal view) and print it somehow in the header of the view (using PHP code). I tried the dsm($page) function but I cant find the proper variable for the field. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a global text in the header. And add the replacement token of the field that you required.
Hope this solves your problem.
[image]

Comment: Thanks buddy. It worked ! Sometimes in searching for the most easy decision, I pass through so many complicated ways. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In the advance part you have Theme Information: that will give you the name of the template which is being used to render your view ( usually the views-view.tpl.php you can create other templates for specific view too). Inside that template you will find this piece of code:

```
 <div class="view-content">
  <?php print $rows; ?>
 </div>
```

dsm($rows) and you will find what you are looking for.